# rewrite attachment url with attachment title

Tags: url-rewriting

I need to rewrite all attachment urls by the following rule

This is the current urls for the attachments:
domain.de/?attachment_id=17806

This is how it should look like:
domain.de/bilder/image_meta_title

This is what i tried - the rule itself is working but the links don't work:

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'attachment_rewrite_rule_14924');

//URL Rewrite Rule for attachments
function wpd_attachment_link( $link, $post_id ){
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $post = $post->post_title;
    $post = str_replace(" ","-",$post);
    return home_url( '/bilder/' . $post);
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_attachment_link', 20, 2 );
```

Can anyone help me and tell what could be possibly wrong here?
As i mentioned before, i get successfully the url rewritten but the url is broken then, it doesn't refer to the attached media.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on **Pretty links** feature of wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks

This feature allow wordpress to rewrite the URL's on the fly. But may need some modifications on the host `.htaccess` file.